# How to use CSS to get 5 buttons aligned like this

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm struggling to get a design like I put in this image in CSS.

I'm using wordpress, and my theme just adds a full image to the top, I would like to make the most of space.

http://antinovaordemmundial.com/test/header.png

I have already all the buttons as single images (at this point I prefered to not to use sprites) and each image has a light version, to show "on-hover".

Thanks

Comment: Technical question .. IMHO should be on Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have created a demo for you Check it http://jsfiddle.net/UvGDj/

Comment: Great Work!!! @emerson you may want to consider using CSS sprites for the backgrounds of each link.  This would be the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. A two column layout, second column (container) float right, give it a fixed with and text-align:center. Let this contain the text on top and the five buttons.

Comment: Hi SriranganThanks for the answer.WOuld you have an example how to do this?